# What is the & Symbol in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this VB code that I am converting for someone, but he didn't comment it, so what does it mean

```vb
Dim Arguments As String = path & "\" & fs & ".freeze" & " ls"
```

Comment: I dont know why you got -1 for the question :P ...

Comment: its been a long time sinse i used vb... be nice

Comment: Using websearch to search for `&` can be tricky

Comment: @David: The first hit for "vb.net ampersand meaning" explains it. Not very hard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `&` operator in Visual Basic is used to concatenate strings. In C# the concatenation operator is `+` and so the direct translation is

```
string Arguments = path + @"\" + fs + ".freeze" + " ls";
```

Better in my view would be to use `Path.Combine`:

```
string Arguments = Path.Combine(path, fs + ".freeze") + " ls";
```

Comment: The question asker may have had a reason not to use Path.Combine in VB.Net.

Comment: @lesderid Yes. Or perhaps it was not used due to lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

That's just string concatenation:

```
string arguments = path + @"\" + fs + ".freeze" + " ls";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private string _arguments = Path.Combine(path, fs + ".freeze") + " ls";
```

This should work.